# Can I edit or extract the contents of an asset bundle in Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I have a Unity assetbundle with me. I have some more bundles inside those and some db files. Is there a simple way to edit or extract the contents of an asset bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity does not support any functionality to do this. But see the other answer for a solution that might work. However you're not really meant to edit them in the first place. Asset bundles are meant to be created from a set of assets and then loaded into your application.

Depending on how they are created, they can be compressed or uncompressed, and there are platform dependent differences. Heck, there's not even an easy way to see what's in there, besides including a default scriptable object with some table of contents.

So if you wish to edit the contents of your asset bundle, edit the original assets and generate a new asset bundle.

Comment: no what i meant was creating a mod of an android game, now that android game is made by using unity, as i have some experience with it so i know that, now yes they do have a scriptable object which tells about the contents of each individual bundle, now all i wanna do is uncompress them, see if they are encrypted or not and edit them , okay if there is no easy way then whats the hard way can you help.....

Comment: Well, if you're trying to mod a game, you'll either have to reverse-engineer asset bundles, or create your own Unity project where you load them, instantiate the data (if you can get the relevant info out of a ScriptableObject) and then see if you can extract your relevant information. But that all goes far beyond the scope of an SO question or answer.

Comment: When people do not know the answer, they should not create an answer that effectively states "I do not know", justified by opinions about why the question "is not possible" to answer.  A comment would suffice.  "Not an easy way" does technically answer the question and also suffices.  However, it is possible to extract assets, otherwise how does Unity access them?  Simply that it is difficult does not mean impossible nor does it necessarily imply some moral imperative about what is meant.  All that is intended by an asset bundle is simply to bundle assets, for efficient distribution.

Answer (score 7):

For people who find this question in the future...

Yes, with [uTinyRipper](https://github.com/mafaca/UtinyRipper).